# Memory Allocation for Function Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a struct called warehouse and a generic linked list and each item points to a warehouse struct.

```
typedef struct linked{
    char type;
    void * item;
    struct linked * next;
    struct linked * prev;
}LinkedList;


typedef struct warehouse{
    char * name;
    float volume;
    float (* getPrice) (void * S);
    float (* getTotalDollarAmount)(void * S);
}house_t;
```

When I tried to get the `getPrice` function pointer point to a function `float price (void *S)`

```
void menu (LinkedList *house){
    char *c;
    float num;
    c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    LinkedList *i;
    i = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList);
    house_t *sk;
    sk = (house_t *) malloc(sizeof(house_t));
    //i->item = (house_t *) malloc(sizeof(house_t));

    scanf("%c", c);

    ((house_t*)i->item)->getPrice = price;
    sk=findhouse(house, c);
    num = ((house_t*)i->item)->getPrice(sk);
    printf("%f",num);
}
```

I got bad access error. Since every time I got a bad access error it was because I didn't allocate memory for something. But do I need to allocate memory for function pointer? If so, how?

Here's some more code

```
float price (void *S)
{
    return ((house_t*)S)->volume;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you allocated memory for `item` did you? Can you show us more initialization code?

Comment: your error seems obvious or you need to put other informations..

Comment: I tried to allocate memory for item using `i->item = (house_t *) malloc(sizeof(house_t))` but got bad access for this line as well.

Comment: @otchkcom Show your code.

Comment: 1. [Don't cast malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html). 2. There's an error in your minimal, compilable testcase, which makes it non-compilable. It's on the line with more '(' than ')': `i = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList);`

Comment: 3. What is `sizeof (char)`? Hint: How many `char`s are there in a `char`?

Comment: ps. We need a minimal, compilable testcase. Minimal means: Using only enough code to reproduce the symptoms of your problem (eg. the segfault). Compilable means: Using enough code to reproduce the symptoms of your problem without having to fix syntax errors (such as above) or guess (eg. what your main looks like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinkedList *i;
i = NewLinkedList();

/* ... snip ... */

LinkedList *NewLinkedList()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

According to your definition of `NewLinkedList()`, the variable `i` is now `NULL`. You try and dereference it with `i->item = ...` but you can't do this if `i` is `NULL`. I think what you really want to do is allocate space for your linked list in your `NewLinkedList` function:

```
LinkedList * NewLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList *result = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    result->type = '\0';  // set to suitable initial value
    result->item = NULL;
    result->next = NULL;
    result->prev = NULL;
    return result;
}
```